# Dagger 2 - Strategies for reducing number of classes which require annotations

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

So I am currently in the process of learning dagger 2, and from the tutorials that I've read so far, for a dependency to be injected, the `@Inject` annotation gets placed inline with fields (for Activities/Fragments) or constructors. However I see that as an issue if I'm not the owner of parts of the code and can't add the required annotations for this technique to work, or if I don't want other parts of the code to know that dagger exists.

The application structure I have at the moment is:

1. App Module - where I'd like to put my DI code in (e.g. dagger modules, etc).
2. Presentation Module - Views/ViewModels etc.
3. Domain Module - Use Cases etc.
4. Data Module - Repositories etc.

With pretty much this style of classes contained in my application:

- `class ExampleViewModelImpl(useCase: ExampleUseCase): ViewModel()` in Presentation (gets initialised from an Activity or similar).
- `class ExampleUseCaseImpl(repository: ExampleRepository): ExampleUseCase` in Domain
- `class ExampleRepositoryImpl(dao: ExampleDao): ExampleRepository` in Data

With the structure above, what is the minimum number of classes outside of the App Module that I need to touch in order to utilize dagger with as much automated dependency injection as possible? Code examples of how this is achieved would be great.

I am unsure of some terminologies, and wasn't able to find a solution online. If there are good resources which explains what I'm asking, that would also be great.

Comment: This is a little off topic but if you want a simple to use DI framework i wold suggest you take a look at Koin. It is a simple DSL written in kotlin for DI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I don't want other parts of the code to know that dagger exists.

`@Inject` is a standard (JSR 330) which Dagger implements. Adding those annotations doesn't have anything to do with Dagger and can be used the same way with other DI frameworks. If it's your code you should just add those `@Inject` annotations where appropriate. Think of them as documentation: What constructor/field/method must be injected to create & use this object?

The only place where your classes will know that Dagger exists is at the same place where you'd be creating the objects otherwise, too.

---

Going down that path, of course you *could* use Dagger without any `@Inject` annotations, but you'd be writing *a lot* of unnecessary boilerplate and missing out on the most powerful feature of Dagger at the same time (code *generation*).

> `@Inject` annotation gets placed inline with fields (for Activities/Fragments) or constructors. However I see that as an issue if I'm not the owner of parts of the code and can't add the required annotations for this technique to work

That's what `@BindsInstance` with the `@Component.Builder` is for (add an object to the component) and what `@Provides` annotated methods are for (create and initialize an object from a module)

If you really want to write code without `@Inject`, then you'd do exactly this *for all of your objects*. This means a *lot* of modules, and even more `@Provides` annotated methods. It will work, but I don't see the point in writing all those methods if a single `@Inject` on the constructor has the same effect.
In my opinion the best thing about Dagger is that I can add / remove / change constructor parameters and don't have to touch any other parts of my code since Dagger will generate new code with the new arguments. In your case you'd have to also change the parameters to the `@Provides` method as well as the constructor invocation.

Next let's look at how to remove `@Inject` from fields. Basically you don't want to do field injection, so instead of writing an injection method in the component, you'd write provision methods.

```
@Component
class MyComponent {

  fun inject(activity: MyActivity)

}

class MyActivity {
  @Inject lateinit var myDep: Dependency

  fun onCreate() {
    component.inject(this)
  }
}
```

Removing the `@Inject` we need to use the provision methods instead.

```
@Component
class MyComponent {

  fun provisionMyDependency() : Dependency

}

class MyActivity {
  lateinit var myDep: Dependency

  fun onCreate() {
    myDep = component.provisionMyDependency()
  }
}
```

It will work and everything, but again, you will miss out on the single best feature of Dagger: Code generation. The example above looks alright because I only added a single dependency, but think about what happens to those 2 different implementations when you add / remove / change dependencies, how well it will scale. If you prefer to do things manually any refactoring will become arduous.

> With the structure above, what is the minimum number of classes outside of the App Module that I need to touch in order to utilize dagger with as much automated dependency injection as possible?

Your question (especially the title) is in direct conflict with your goal. If you don't want to use those annotations, then you can't use Dagger code generation & injection but have to resort to do it manually as highlighted above.

> with as much automated dependency injection as possible

To best utilize Dagger you add `@Inject` on the constructor and/or fields of every class that should end up on your dependency graph and let Dagger do its thing.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This is all new to me, and will try to use `@Inject` where applicable since it is not a dagger specific annotation.